# Remove continuous duplicate

Tags: c++, vectors, c++03

I've made a little function to eliminate continuous duplicate from a `std::vector`. I have to use C++03.

For example, if a vector of ints is composed of: 1,1,2,3,,3,1,1,2 my function should return 1,2,3,1,2. I've tried to use templates (I've just began to use c++) and made it as fast as possible!

```
template<class T>
vector<T> remove_duplicate(vector<T>& vec) {
    int length = vec.size();
    vector<T> result(length);
    result[0] = vec[0];
    int last = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if(vec[i] != result[last]){
            last++;
            result[last] = vec[i];
        }
    result.resize(last+1);
    return result;
}
```

Here's a simple test case:

```
static
void test_remove_duplicate() {
    vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1); //123131
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(1);

    vector<int> v1;
    v1 = remove_duplicate(v);
    for(int i=0; i<v1.size(); i++) {
        cout << v1[i];
    } cout << endl;
}
```

What do you think about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's go through mechanical errors:

1. use `size_t` instead of `int`

   ```
   int length = vec.size();
   ```
2. what if there is no zero element?

   ```
   result[0] = vec[0];
   ```
3. the same as first:

   ```
   int last = 0;
   ```
4. the same as 1, 3:

   ```
   for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
   ```

Optimization errors:

1. Is there any reason why do you need to return a COPY of vector? If you need return copy, so why do you pass it by reference?
2. Extra `resize` of vector is extremely heavy and slow operation.

   ```
   result.resize(last+1);
   ```
3. Prefer pre-increment to post-increment
4. use reserve and push_back, instead of resize and []. In you case result.size() <= v.size(). So, make following:

   ```
   std::vector<T> result;
   result.reserve(v.size);
   result.push_back( vec[0] );
   ```

   In the loop:

   ```
   result.push_back( vec[i] );
   ```

So, including all comments above:

```
template<class T>
std::vector<T> remove_duplicate(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::vector<T> result;

    if(!vec.empty())
    {
        result.reserve(vec.size());
        result.push_back(vec.front());

        for(size_t i = 0; i< vec.size(); ++i)
            if(vec[i] != result.back())
                result.push_back( vec[i] );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: whithout last resize if i try to use the vector with a for loop ended in size() it continue with some trail 0..

Comment: resize() to a smaller size than capacity does not have any nasty side-effects only that current size will be reduced. But I agree that I would prefer to use reserve() and push_back() instead.

Answer (score 1):

## Know your Standard Library

The standard `unique` algorithm performs exactly this task (and is available in C++03).  If we take the argument by value, we can modify it in place, and use the erase-remove idiom:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
std::vector<T> remove_duplicate(std::vector<T> vec) {
    vec.erase(std::unique(vec.begin(), vec.end()), vec.end());
    return vec;
}
```

Note that the result vector has the same capacity as the input vector.  If this is likely to be a problem, then `std::unique_copy()` could be used to copy values into a new vector, or a move to C++11 would gain the `shrink_to_fit()` method on your vector.